# Positioning a div

Tags: html, css

Was wondering would anyone be able to help, I'm trying to position a div but it doesn't seem to be moving at all. Here is the code :

```css
.gallery-photos clearfix {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
.gallery-photos {
  padding: 20px;
}
.gallery-photos .big-photo {
  display: block;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  margin-right: 210px;
}
.gallery-photos .big-photo img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.gallery-photos .photo-thumbnails {
  float: right;
  width: 210px;
}
.gallery-photos .photo-thumbnails .thumbnail {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 30%;
  height: 63px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  margin-left: 3.33333%;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
.gallery-photos .photo-thumbnails .thumbnail.current {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.gallery-photos .photo-thumbnails .thumbnail .thumbnail-inner {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.gallery-photos .photo-thumbnails .thumbnail img {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-photos clearfix">
  <div class="photo-thumbnails">
    <div class="thumbnail current">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="images/5.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="images/6.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="big-photo" class="big-photo">
    <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you also mention which div and where?

Comment: They are all in the left hand corner of the screen, I want to get them to the centre of the page

Answer (score 2):

Change this selector: `.gallery-photos clearfix{` to `.gallery-photos.clearfix{`

For centering the element you can do this:

```
.gallery-photos.clearfix{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Comment: still doesn't seem to be moving, any other suggestions?

Comment: @EricaManning I have updated my answer so I'm not sure if you tried the updated version (`.gallery-photos.clearfix` vs. `.gallery-photos .clearfix`)

Comment: That seems to be working now, but the big photo div doesn't appear on the page anymore

Comment: @EricaManning - The easiest way is to set width in pixels to `.gallery-photos`

Comment: @EricaManning - I added another edit to help you with the centering part

Answer (score 1):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/31/

HTML

```
<div class="gallery-photos clearfix">
  <div class="photo-thumbnails">
    <div class="thumbnail current">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner"> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" /> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner"> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" /> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner"> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" /> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner"> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" /> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner"> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" /> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner"> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" /> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner"> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" /> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner"> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" /> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner"> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" /> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="big-photo" class="big-photo"> <img src="http://placehold.it/900x600" alt="" /> </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .gallery-photos.clearfix{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -50px;
}


.gallery-photos {
    padding: 20px;
}

.gallery-photos .big-photo {
    display: block;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    margin-right: 210px;
}

.gallery-photos .big-photo img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}



.gallery-photos .photo-thumbnails {
    float: right;
    width: 210px;

}

.gallery-photos .photo-thumbnails .thumbnail {
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 30%;
    height: 63px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    margin-left: 3.33333%;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    opacity: 0.4;
}

.gallery-photos .photo-thumbnails .thumbnail.current {
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.gallery-photos .photo-thumbnails .thumbnail .thumbnail-inner {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery-photos .photo-thumbnails .thumbnail img {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: The first selector is wrong, it should be `.gallery-photos.clearfix` (without spaces)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `position: absolute`, use `position: relative` on the parent ( in your case `body { position: relative }`.  It's easier if you set a height and width on body as well (in your case `100vw` x `100vh` on `body` which is the full viewport (the whole viewable area).

```css
html,

body {

  position: relative;

  height: 100vh;

  width: 100vw;

}

.gallery-photos.clearfix {

  position: absolute;

  top: 50%;

  left: 50%;

  margin-top: -50px;

  margin-left: -50px;

}

.gallery-photos {

  padding: 20px;

}

.gallery-photos .big-photo {

  display: block;

  background-color: #ffffff;

  padding: 3px;

  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;

  margin-right: 210px;

}

.gallery-photos .big-photo img {

  display: block;

  max-width: 100%;

  height: auto;

  margin: 0 auto;

}

.gallery-photos .photo-thumbnails {

  float: right;

  width: 210px;

}

.gallery-photos .photo-thumbnails .thumbnail {

  float: left;

  box-sizing: border-box;

  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;

  width: 30%;

  height: 63px;

  cursor: pointer;

  padding: 3px;

  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;

  margin-left: 3.33333%;

  margin-bottom: 6px;

  opacity: 0.4;

}

.gallery-photos .photo-thumbnails .thumbnail.current {

  opacity: 1;

  background-color: #ffffff;

}

.gallery-photos .photo-thumbnails .thumbnail .thumbnail-inner {

  height: 100%;

  overflow: hidden;

}

.gallery-photos .photo-thumbnails .thumbnail img {

  display: block;

  width: auto;

  max-height: 100%;

  margin: 0 auto;

}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-photos clearfix">
  <div class="photo-thumbnails">
    <div class="thumbnail current">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/210/000/0f0.png&text=IMG" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/210/0e0/aa0.png&text=IMG" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/210/ff0/07c.png&text=IMG"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/210/4cd/b40.png&text=IMG"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/210/9e0/160.png&text=IMG"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/210/e56/111.png&text=IMG"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/210/05f/7be.png&text=IMG"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/210/6d0/5ae.png&text=IMG"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/210/fa8/9f0.png&text=IMG"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="big-photo" class="big-photo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/480x320/000/0f0.png&text=IMG" />
  </div>
</div>
```